# Why std::string makes WSAGetLastError returning zero?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, winapi, winsock

Someday. I wrote Socket wrapper class like Python built-in socket library for C++ (Visual Studio 2015)

All functions are working very well. However, I found some functions I wrotten has a problem.

After using `std::string`'s method like `.size()`, `.clear()`, `WSAGetLastError()` always return zero.

```
std::string str = "Hello, world";
size_t recvsz = ::send(socket, str.c_str(), str.size(), 0);

// Why always return zero after using std::string's methods?
int err = ::WSAGetLastError();
```

Therfore, I can't know socket states, socket is dead, or socket is still waiting for receiving data.

So, I used a method storing `WSAGetLastError()` returning value before `std::string`'s methods and then restoring it using `WSASetLastError()`.

```
std::string str = "Hello, world";

// Before using std::string's methods
int err = ::WSAGetLastError();

size_t recvsz = ::send(socket, str.c_str(), str.size(), 0);

// Restore error value after std::string's methods
::WSASetLastError(err);
```

Is it correct way I used? or why `std::string` makes last error returing zero?

edited: wow... I mistake.. :(. I use ::send not ::recv. sorry for confusing you

```
SOCKET socket;
char buf[100] = {0x00,};
std::string data, temp_buf;
ssize_t recvsz = ::recv(socket, buf, 99, 0);

// When err has proper error code before std::string methods
// It just for a test
// int err = ::WSAGetLastError();

temp_buf = buf;
data += buf;

int err = WSAGetLastError(); // Always return zero!
```

Comment: If you're actually using C++17 and not C++11, you may be able to call `str.data()` to get a non-const buffer instead.

Comment: The return value of WSAGetLastError() is entirely unpredictable when the function did not fail.  Fix your code, only ever call it when recv() returns SOCKET_ERROR.

Comment: How do you know that the zero isn't set by `recv`? Are you forcing it to fail?

Comment: what you doing *before* `recv` absolute unrelated to `WSAGetLastError` *after* `recv` in case it fail

Comment: *Is it correct way I used?* - no, wrong. you must use `WSAGetLastError` which set `send`, in case it fail, but not restore it to state before

Comment: @RbMm Hmmm. The codes are used for my socket wrapper class in function "int recv(const std::string& str);". So. I did't care regard of this.

Comment: i not understand in what your problem at all

Comment: @RbMm Sorry for my short english. I added new code below my question.

Comment: but you need call `WSAGetLastError` just after `send` fail, before any another calls.

Comment: @RbMm Hmm... Okay... I  need to more study  how std::string works.  Thank you for you answer :).

Comment: no, this is unrelated to string at all. simply if some api (which use last error) fail - need just call `GetLastError` - before any another api calls

Answer (score 4):

Because you committed a gross indiscretion by writing into read-only memory that you don't own. In short, you blatted your computer's memory and now your program won't work predictably.

With a compliant C++11 compiler, you could do:

```
ssize_t recvsz = ::recv(socket, &str[0], str.size(), 0);
```

That's because `&str[0]` is a pointer to the actual string buffer (in a non-`const` context), and because from C++11 that data is guaranteed to be stored 
contiguously. Technically, before then, not so much (though in practice it basically always is).

Otherwise you're going to have to allocate a little `char[]` buffer of your own, into which to receive data. You can just give it automatic storage duration with practically no cost, unless you're on a embedded system with tight resource constraints (but then you wouldn't be using `string` anyway).

By the way, be careful of your return types: `size_t` is unsigned. `recv` returns a **`ssize_t`** which is signed and may be negative to indicate an error condition.

```
const size_t BUF_SIZE = 256;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

ssize_t recvsz = ::recv(socket, &buf[0], BUF_SIZE, 0);
if (recvsz < 0) {
   // ... handling
}

// Now, optionally:
std::string str(buf, recvsz);
```

Now, with all that fixed, the answer is that [the "last error" is permitted to be changed even by a successful operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx). So, yes, you'll have to save then re-set a previous "last error" value if you want it to be retained. This does seem to be of dubious value — why do you not handle the error where it is generated? Carrying on after causing an error seems like a bad way to do business.

Comment: Ah!, It is same problem to use ::recv to receive data to non-const buffer memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write to the internal buffer of `std::string` this way. It is managed by the object and you must use functions like [`append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) or [`assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) to update it, so the string can track its current content and length.

Moreover, `c_str()` returns `const char*` pointer and you cannot write to such memory.

If you are sure, that you will always write the correct amount of bytes (so the size data written and the actual length of data stored internally will match), you can use [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) to get the reference to a particular character inside the string (presumably, the first one in your case) and use its address as the target buffer.

---

As @AndyG noticed in his comment, C++ 17 introduced [`std::basic_string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) which also returns pointer to the actual buffer.

Your code should take one of the following forms:

```
size_t recvsz = ::recv(socket, &str[0], str.size(), 0);

size_t recvsz = ::recv(socket, str.data(), str.size(), 0); // C++ 17, str must not be const
```

Comment: You can write over the internal buffer, but the result of `.c_str()` may not be that buffer. And, even if it is, the `const`ness means the program has UB so anything can happen (this bit you said).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally agree. However, to ensure proper behavior and keep string's state consistent, you must ensure, that you always write the correct amount of bytes. In case of differences, this would involve additional calls to `resize()`.

Comment: Sorry.. I used ::send not ::recv in this question. but same probloem is also occured using both ::recv and ::send

Comment: @pr0ximo - *but same probloem* - which the problem at all ?

Comment: Variable "socket" is an asynchronous socket. Using ::recv function, I want to receive data from remote host to buffer named as "char buf[100]". A function ::recv would not be receive data from remote. Therefore, using a function WSAGetLastError(), I can know socket state that I will try receive later or I will disconnect host. But, After using std::string method(.append(), .size()), WSAGetLastError() is always return zero.

Comment: `.size()` does absolutely nothing to the value returned by `WSAGetLastError()`, as there is no Win32 API call being made. `std::string` keeps track of its own size at all times, and `.size()` simply returns that current value. `.append()` *might* affect `WSAGetLastError()`, since it *may* have to allocate new memory, which may have to come from the OS at that time if the `Allocator` has run out of internal memory. `WSAGetLastError()` is just an alias for `GetLastError()`, and memory allocation functions like `LocalAlloc()`, `VirtualAlloc()`, etc use `GetLastError()` to report allocation errors

Comment: If `recv()` fails, you need to call `WSAGetLastError()` **immediately**, before doing *anything else* that might alter the calling thread's current error state.